# Can't delete from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4J DB (version 2.1.1, community edition) which I am using for testing. I need to tear down before running my tests so I run the following:

```
MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n,r
```

After having no problems, I have started getting the following error (in the browser console)

```
Position[12884901888] requested for high id[168718], store is ok[true] recovery[false]
```

When I have run the consistency check tool I get the following:

```
Active logical log detected, this might be a source of inconsistencies.
Consider allowing the database to recover before running the consistency check.
Consistency checking will continue, abort if you wish to perform recovery first.
To perform recovery before checking consistency, use the '--recovery' flag.
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: Unable to lock store[/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.1/libexec/data/graph.db/neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names]
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.checkStorage(cct.sc4122648793073465175.tmp:169)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(cct.sc4122648793073465175.tmp:111)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(cct.sc4122648793073465175.tmp:74)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.DynamicStringStore.<init>(cct.sc4122648793073465175.tmp:40)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Bobby

Comment: Please update to 2.1.2 to avoid these issues. Would it be possible to share such a database with this behavior? E.g. as zip-file on dropbox?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'll try 2.1.2 today. I'm happy to share the db, as it's just test data.

Comment: Please share a dropbox-link with michael at neo4j.org then. Thanks!

Comment: I'd love to hear back from you if this happens on 2.1.2 too.